# change database PostgreSQL to MySQL

Tags: jhipster

I'm very new to coding world so I hope I will be clear in my request.

I would like to know if in an Jhipster generated app, I can change the prodDatabaseType from PostgreSQL to MySQL directly in the file .yo-rc.json without the need to generate de novo an other JHipster app?

I have another naive question. Does Spring JPA handle the request for MySQL and PostgreSQL the same way?

Comment: Please provide some example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-generating with MySQL (after modifying `.yo-rc.json`) will change few properties in `application*.yml`, `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`, docker files, Liquibase xml changelogs and ID generation type in JPA entities.

Knowing this, you should be able to easily merge these changes using git.